# conjure-up openstack failure

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, cloud, conjure-up

I ran `conjure-up openstack`, selected maas, entered the server IP address and port, and my API key, clicked continue, and got this result:

[image]

Any recommendations for deploying Openstack using conjure-up?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're following the instructions on http://conjure-up.io, you're using an older version of Juju 2 (probably a beta version) where that --upload-tools flag has since been removed.

Basically

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:conjure-up/next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conjure-up
```

Comment: but Autopilot work with MAAS 2.0 and JUJU 2.0 right?

Comment: Autopilot is currently in testing for supporting both MAAS 2.x and Juju 2.x but it is not currently ready for public consumption yet.